# How best to bite-size a form in Django, with no data persistence: What's the most Djangonic method?

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Firstly, the scenario in my question:

I want to deliver a form in bitesize stages, with the valid completion of one stage leading to the next until all stages are complete.

On completion, I'd like to use data once, and then forget it completely so I'm not holding on to any user data at all.

My options as I see it are:

1. Multiple views each with a unique form all bound to a single model. The final submit button in the chain triggers data in the model to be accessed, used and then that particular row removed.
2. Multiple views each with unbound forms, each adding data to a cookie, which is then read on the final submit, data used and the cookie deleted (either using sessions or plain old js hard coded into each template).
3. A single view and template containing a single unbound form, which progressively un-hides divs containing each stage until all stages are completed and final 'submit' posts data from the form, allows a view to process it and forgets it.

I can actualise all three of the above, but which is the most 'Djangonic' method, or is there a better method still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library made from the Django guys for this case: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

It's not dynamic though, so when you click "proceed", it will render a new page. But you can probably write a javascript module, that can handle this. But I wouldn't go that far, it's a lot of work for little benefit. Just just django-form-tools and use the wizard you want and do whatever you need in the `done` stage of your view.